# Integrating Javascript functions to the HTML file generated from Adobe Muse

Tags: javascript, html, adobe, muse

I have a html file, css and js files generated by Adobe Muse tool. When each button is clicked, i want to call some Js function and need to perform the same. I want to know how to integrate the Javascript code with the html file generated from Adobe Muse. My HTML file generated from the Adobe Muse is shared below.

```
http://pastebin.com/wDrWEmm6
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're just wanting to add your own custom Javascript to an Adobe Muse page. In Muse, this is how you would do it:

To quote Fjenngard from https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1180317

> 1. right click on your page
> 2. choose page properties
> 3. choose metadata
> 4. add javascript in head section   `<script type="text/javascript"> ... </script>` or choose object and then insert html you can right
>      click that object and choose edit html and (re)write code.